# How to set default selection for combo box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I am using [`.tmpl()`](http://api.jquery.com/tmpl/) to fill out templates like so

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="template">
  <form action="" method="post">
    <div>
      <div> ${ID} </div>
      <div> <input name="title" id="${ID}_title" value="${title}" type="text" /> </div>
      <label> Section (${section}) </label> &nbsp;
      <select name="section" id="${ID}_section">
        <option value="">-- Select --</option>
        <option value="aaa">AAA</option>
        <option value="bbb">BBB</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
</script>
```

where `${section}` wil contain either the combo box value `aaa` or `bbb`.

How do I set the default selection for the combo box according to `${section}`?

Comment: That is not a drdown list, not a [combobox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combo_box)

Comment: I am sorry but does the `<script>...</script>` contain HTML code?

Comment: @Talha Ahmed Khan the OP is using jquery templates see the script type

Comment: for update2: a template script tag needs: type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" and variable can't be created that way inside it... new jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/3TrEY/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like:

```
<select name="section" id="${ID}_section">
    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
    <option value="aaa" {{if $section == 'aaa'}} selected="selected" {{/if}}>AAA</option>
    <option value="bbb" {{if $section == 'bbb'}} selected="selected" {{/if}}>BBB</option>
</select>
```

**Update**
Well my jsfiddle in comment was just a way to simulate your setup, because you don't attached it in this post. If $section == bbb or aaa try this:

```
 <select name="section" id="${ID}_section">
    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
    <option value="aaa" {{if section == 'aaa'}} selected="selected" {{/if}}>AAA</option>
    <option value="bbb" {{if section == 'bbb'}} selected="selected" {{/if}}>BBB</option>
</select>
```

Otherwise more code is needed, how do you call your template and how is $section assigned.

**Update 2**
try: http://jsfiddle.net/3TrEY/6/

Comment: For some reason the last option does always get the selection. Could it be that `==` is a boolean compare? Have also tried with `eq` and that gives the same.

Comment: When I View Source in the browser, I can see `{{if 'bbb' == 'aaa'}} selected="selected" {{/if}}`. Am I suppose to be able to see that?